# why are these two strings not equal in c

Tags: c, http, parsing, cs50

hey guys ok i wrote this code which would check if a get request is proper but at the last comparison it doesn't give me the expected result thank you in advance the problem is in the last if statement it return false when it should return true

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* string="GET /cats.html HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    if(strncmp(string,"GET ",4)==0)
    {
        printf("hello");
        if(string[4]=='/')
        {
            printf(",\n");
            char* string1=strchr(string,'.');
            string1=strchr(string1,' ');
            printf("%s",string1);
            if(string1!=NULL)
            {
                if(*string1==" HTTP/1.1\r\n")
                {
                    printf("world\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output and what do you actually get?

Comment: it should print hello,world but it stops at hello,

Comment: Your compiler should warn. Never ignore compiler warnings. And enable the recommended warnings.

Comment: @islam zidan: `*string1==" HTTP/1.1\r\n"` is not valid C code. Your compiler undoubtedly told you about that. Did you just ignore your compiler's diagnostic messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
if(*string1==" HTTP/1.1\r\n")
```

does not compare whether two strings are equal.

type of `string1` is `char*`. Hence type of `*string1` is `char`.

Hence, you are comparing a `char` with a `char const*`, which is far from what you expected.

Even using

```
if(string1==" HTTP/1.1\r\n")
```

will not give you the expected result since it will compare two pointers for equality, which will be false in this use case all the time.

What you need to use is the library function to compare two strings.

```
if( strcmp(string1, " HTTP/1.1\r\n") == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not comparing strings, you are comparing pointers to strings.

The proper comparison would be:

```
if(!strcmp(string1," HTTP/1.1\r\n")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: it worked thank you very much  my reputation is still low so i can't vote and the answer will be accepted in 11 minutes

Comment: You got my "two cents" into your rep. ;)

Comment: @Serge: "...you are comparing pointers to strings...". Where does the OP compare pointers to strings? `*string1` is not a "pointer to string".